# replace fragment in fragmentstatepageradapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

i need to disable a fragment based on the menu id array retrieved from the server. i already retrieved the menu id but i do not know how to replace the equivalent fragment for that id. do i need to use fragmentmanager and fragmenttransaction. i can't use getSupportFragmentManager or getFragmentManager in FragmentStatePagerAdapter. i used framelayout before but not viewpager. please help

this is my code

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;
    String tabName;
    PreferencesHelper prefHelp;
    final FragmentManager disablefm;
    SharedPreferences disabledMenu;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    Context ctx;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
        disablefm = fm;
        ctx = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                CallFragment tab1 = new CallFragment();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                ChatFragment tab2 = new ChatFragment();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                RoomServiceMenu tab3 = new RoomServiceMenu();
                return tab3;
            case 3:
                HouseKeepingFragment tab4 = new HouseKeepingFragment();
                //MealFragment tab4 = new MealFragment();
                return tab4;
            case 4:
                //dnd
                DndFragment tab5 = new DndFragment();
                return tab5;
            case 5:

                //open door
                OpenDoorFragment tab6 = new OpenDoorFragment();
                return tab6;
            case 6:
                ServiceFragment tab7 = new ServiceFragment();
                return tab7;
            case 7:

                //chauffeur
                ChauffeurFragment tab8 = new ChauffeurFragment();
                return tab8;
            case 8:
                SpecialOfferFragment tab9 = new SpecialOfferFragment();
                return tab9;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    private void loadPref(){
        disabledMenu = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        int disabledmenuSize = Integer.parseInt(prefHelp.getPreferences("disable menu length"));
        String disabledMenuarray[] = new String[disabledmenuSize];
        Log.d("log1", "disabled menu len: "+disabledmenuSize);
        for(int u = 0; u < disabledmenuSize; u++){

            disabledMenuarray[u] = prefHelp.getPreferences("disabledMenuId"+u);
            Log.d("log1", "disabled menu id# "+u+" id: "+Arrays.toString(disabledMenuarray));
            if(Arrays.asList(disabledMenuarray).contains("20")){
                Log.d("log1", "main | pref contain id 20");
                //disable call fragment
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey i already figured out how to do what i want.

here's my code:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;
    String tabName;
    PreferencesHelper prefHelp;
    FragmentManager disablefm;
    SharedPreferences disabledMenu;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    Context ctx;
    Boolean roomSrvOn, houseKeepOn, dndOn, doorOn, spaOn, chauffeurOn, offerOn, callOn;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
        disablefm = fm;
        ctx = context;
        disabledMenu = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        Log.d("log1", "pager ctx: "+ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        roomSrvOn = true;
        houseKeepOn = true;
        dndOn = true;
        doorOn = true;
        spaOn = true;
        chauffeurOn = true;
        offerOn = true;
        callOn = true;
        //disable menu

        prefHelp = new PreferencesHelper(ctx);
        int disabledmenuSize = ((MainActivity)ctx).disabledmenuSize;
        String disabledMenuarray[] = new String[disabledmenuSize];
        Log.d("log1", "pager | disabled menu len: "+disabledmenuSize);
        for(int u = 0; u < disabledmenuSize; u++){

            disabledMenuarray[u] = prefHelp.getPreferences("disabledMenuId"+u);
            Log.d("log1", "pager | disabled menu id# "+u+" id: "+Arrays.toString(disabledMenuarray));
            if(Arrays.asList(disabledMenuarray).contains("20")){
                Log.d("log1", "pager | call disabled");
                callOn = false;
            }else if(Arrays.asList(disabledMenuarray).contains("10")){
                Log.d("log1", "pager | room service disabled");
                roomSrvOn = false;
            }else if(Arrays.asList(disabledMenuarray).contains("8")){
                Log.d("log1", "pager | house keeping disabled");
                houseKeepOn = false;
            }else if(Arrays.asList(disabledMenuarray).contains("17")){
                Log.d("log1", "pager | dnd disabled");
                dndOn = false;
            }else if(Arrays.asList(disabledMenuarray).contains("14")){
                Log.d("log1", "pager | open door disabled");
                doorOn = false;
            }else if(Arrays.asList(disabledMenuarray).contains("11")){
                Log.d("log1", "pager | spa disabled");
                spaOn = false;
            }else if(Arrays.asList(disabledMenuarray).contains("19")){
                Log.d("log1", "pager | chauffuer disabled");
                chauffeurOn = false;
            }else if(Arrays.asList(disabledMenuarray).contains("18")){
                Log.d("log1", "pager | offer disabled");
                offerOn = false;
            }
        }

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                if(callOn == false){
                    DisabledFragment tab1 = new DisabledFragment();
                    return tab1;
                }else {
                    CallFragment tab1 = new CallFragment();
                    return tab1;
                }

            case 1:
                    ChatFragment tab2 = new ChatFragment();
                    return tab2;
            case 2:
                if(roomSrvOn == false){
                    DisabledFragment tab3 = new DisabledFragment();
                    return tab3;
                }else {
                    RoomServiceMenu tab3 = new RoomServiceMenu();
                    return tab3;
                }
            case 3:
                if(houseKeepOn == false){
                    DisabledFragment tab4 = new DisabledFragment();
                    return tab4;
                }else {
                    HouseKeepingFragment tab4 = new HouseKeepingFragment();
                    //MealFragment tab4 = new MealFragment();
                    return tab4;
                }
            case 4:
                if(dndOn == false){
                    DisabledFragment tab5 = new DisabledFragment();
                    return tab5;
                }else {
                    //dnd
                    DndFragment tab5 = new DndFragment();
                    return tab5;
                }
            case 5:
                if(doorOn == false){
                    DisabledFragment tab6 = new DisabledFragment();
                    return tab6;
                }else {
                    //open door
                    OpenDoorFragment tab6 = new OpenDoorFragment();
                    return tab6;
                }
            case 6:
                if(spaOn == false){
                    DisabledFragment tab7 = new DisabledFragment();
                    return tab7;
                }else {
                    ServiceFragment tab7 = new ServiceFragment();
                    return tab7;
                }
            case 7:
                if(chauffeurOn == false){
                    DisabledFragment tab8 = new DisabledFragment();
                    return tab8;
                }else {
                    //chauffeur
                    ChauffeurFragment tab8 = new ChauffeurFragment();
                    return tab8;
                }
            case 8:
                if(offerOn == false){
                    DisabledFragment tab9 = new DisabledFragment();
                    return tab9;
                }else {
                    SpecialOfferFragment tab9 = new SpecialOfferFragment();
                    return tab9;
                }
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create NameFragment extend Fragment

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

example

```
public class YourNameFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_name_xml_framgent, container, false);

//Enter code here

return root;
 }
```

In OnCreateView is place you can write code

Comment: R.id.content_main is id of FrameLayout

Comment: i am using viewpager how do i do that. also where do i put that piece of code

Comment: Or see tutorial : https://guides.codepath.com/android/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: do you think i could use setCurrentItem. also where in the tutorial is the part for replacing fragments

Comment: What is the your problem??

Comment: because what i want is when a fragment is disabled based on the array retrieved from the server i will replace that fragment with the "disabled" fragment which contain an image with the disabled image and text